# Is it possible to ferment fresh coconut or its water?

Tags: fermentation, coconut

Has anyone ever fermented fresh coconut or its water and produced an edible probiotic that tasted good and did not make you sick?

Answer (score 4):

In a word, yes.

According to [MakeSauerkraut.com](https://www.makesauerkraut.com/fermented-coconut-water/) (of all places)

> To make fermented coconut water, the sweet water is mixed with a
>   culture (milk kefir grains, water kefir grains, whey from yogurt or a
>   powdered starter) and left to ferment for 18 to 48 hours in a warm
>   place.

There seems to be a lot of recipes out there for such a thing, a quick internet search for "ferment coconut water" should yield more recipes, methods and the like.